# How do I set workbook as fpath & listboxvalue

Tags: excel, runtime-error, concatenation, listboxitem, vba

> Encounter Runtime Error 424, Object Required

For code below

```
 Public fpath as string, fwbk As Workbook


 Private Sub BtnCloseWoSaving_Click()
 'Error on code below
 Set fwbk = fpath & Me.ListBoxWbk.Value 
 End Sub
```

I'm using a userform to open files, close & automate data.
Stuck at this stage of setting opened file as workbook.

Thanks for the help in advance (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public fpath as string, fwbk As Workbook


 Private Sub BtnCloseWoSaving_Click()
 'Error on code below
 Set fwbk = workbooks.open(fpath & Me.ListBoxWbk.Value )
  '    ...
 End Sub
```